# jquery find image based on "align"

Tags: jquery, image, alignment

I'm trying to find all the images on a page based on their alignment (no class or id attached to these images), although I'm not sure how to do it. Basically I want to add CSS to images which are aligned to the right, yet leave the other images as they are.

If anyone could help out, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about *img[align="top"]*  ?

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this selector?

```
$('img[align=right]').addClass('onRight');
```

or if that doesn't work, it might help if you showed us some of your HTML

Comment: yep, works great thank you for your help. Nikita got in first with the answer though :)

Comment: So using `top` gets your right aligned images, or did I miss something?